# Qual a melhor forma de alinhar minhas divs uma ao lado da outra?

Tags: html5, css3

Olá, não estou conseguindo alinhar as duas divs de notícias uma ao lado da outra. Podem ajudar por favor?

```css
/* CSS Document */
body {
  margin-top: -1;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  
}
.top1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}

.top_1_1 {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: -0.8%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    padding-top: 0.5%;
    background-color: black;
    
        
}
.top_2_2 {
  display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.logo {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
    margin: -1%;
}
.top_2_email {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
.top_2_dolar {
  
  width: 15%;
  height: 20%;
  line-height: 2%;
margin-left: 60%;
    margin-top: -6%;
}
.top_2_pesquisar {
    
     width: 10%;
  height: 20%;
    margin-left: 77.2%;
    margin-top: -5%
    
    
    
    
}


.top_1_1 {
    
    
}

top ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1%;
color: aliceblue; }

top UL LI {
  text-decoration-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  padding: -45;
  display: INLINE;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

hr {
    
border-width: 0; 
    height: 5px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border: 1,5px solid; 
    background: black;
    margin-left: -1%;
    width: 100%;
    
    
    
}
.menu_principal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1.5%;

    
 
}
menu ul {
 width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  margin-left: -1%;
  padding: 0;
    
    
}
MENU UL LI {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 12.74px;
    
    margin-right: 1.7%;
}



.hr_sub_menu {
    
border-width: 0; 
    height: 0.5px;
    border-top-width: 0.5px;
    border: 1,5px solid; 
    background: gray;
    margin-left: -1%;
    width: 100%;
    
    
}

.ads {
    
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -1;
    
    
}

.ads img {
    width: 100%;
margin-left: -1%;
    
}

article {
    
    
    
}

.noticia-principal {
    
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 65%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: -1%;

}

 #first-h6-noticiaprincipal {
    
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: -3%;

    
}

 #second-h6-noticiaprincipal {
    
    color: red;
    margin-top: -2%;
    margin-right: -1%;

    
}

.noticia-principal ul {

    padding-left: 3%;
     line-height: 1.5;
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><circle fill="red" cx="7" cy="7" r="2"/></svg>');


    
}


.barra-vermelha {
    
    
    width: 60%;
    font-size: 70%;
    background: linear-gradient(18deg, rgba(255,66,66,1) 30%, rgba(252,32,58,1) 100%);

}
    
.barra-vermelha div:first-child {
    
    display: inline-block;
    color: aliceblue;
    
}

.vl {
    display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  height: 20px;
    
    margin-right: 7%;
    
 
}

#barravermelha2texto{
    display: inline-block;
    
    color: aliceblue;
    
    
}

.noticia-lateral {
    
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    
    
}
.noticia-lateral div {
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;

    border-style: solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    

    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen" />
<style></style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>UOL - Seu universo online</title>
</head>

<body>
<top class="top1">
  <div class="top_1_1">
    <ul>
      <li>BATE-PAPO</li>
      <li>UOL MEU NEGOCIO</li>
      <li>ESTUDE ONLINE</li>
      <li>UOL PLAY</li>
      <li>PAGBANK</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top_2_2">
    <div class="logo"><img src="novo-logo-uol-2021-sem-fundo-1024x576.png" width="100%" height="10%"></div>
    <div class="top_2_email"> <img src="logo-uol-mail.png" width="100%" height="100%"> </div>
    <div class="top_2_dolar">
      <p>Dolar: 5,375</p>
      <p>Euro: 6,255</p>
    </div>
    <div class="top_2_pesquisar">
      <form action="submit" >
        <input placeholder="Pesquisar" type="search" width="5px">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</top>
<hr >
<div class="top3"></div>
<menu class="menu_principal">
  <ul>
    <li>PRODUTOS</li>
    <li>NOTICIAS</li>
    <li>CARROS</li>
    <li>ECONOMIA</li>
    <li>FOLHA</li>
    <li>ESPORTE</li>
    <li>SPLASH</li>
    <li>TV E FAMOSOS</li>
    <li>UNIVERSA</li>
    <li id="#viva-bem">VIVA BEM</li>
  </ul>
</menu>
<hr class="hr_sub_menu">
<div class="ads"><img src="imgs/banner_uolmn_criadordesites_academia-2.jpg"> </div>
<article >
  <div class="noticia-principal">
    <h6 id="first-h6-noticiaprincipal">TENSÃO ENTRE PODERES</h6>
    <h1>Bolsonaro ignora apelos e formaliza pedido de impeachment contra Moraes</h1>
    <h6 id="second-h6-noticiaprincipal">Medida do presidente intensifica crise institucional entre Planalto e Judiciário</h6>
    
      <ul>
      <li>Renan critica pedido de impeachment; senadores dizem que não vai passar</li>
    <li>Fachin relata ação de Bolsonaro contra inquéritos do STF sem parecer da PGR</li>
    <li>Kotscho: 7 de Setembro será um divisor de águas na nossa frágil democracia</li>
    <li>Oyama: Eduardo revela truque e intenção que nunca saiu da cabeça do pai</li>
    <li> Carolina Brígido: Bolsonaro atira pedras, STF responde com bombardeio</li>
          </ul>
  </div>
    
    <aside class="noticia-lateral">
    
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
    
    </aside>
    
    <div class="barra-vermelha">
    <div>NOTÍCIAS DA PANDEMIA</div>
        
    <div id="barravermelha2">
        <div id="barravermelha2texto">Fiocruz entrega hoje 3,9 milhões de doses de vacina ao PNI</div>
        <div class="vl"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  
    
    
</article>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

[image: MINHA TELA]

[image: TELA QUE ESTOU COPIANDO]

Answer (score -2):

para esse tipo de posicionamento é interessante fazer uso das funcionalidades do flexbox. Neste caso, você pode, na *div* que contém as duas notícias aplicar o seguinte:

```
.barra-vermelha {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

dessa forma você garante que, as tags que estiverem contidas na div que possui a classe 'barra-vermelha', ficarão dispostas uma ao lado da outra conforme deseja.